# Discrimination and differences of treatment

Tags: relocation, discrimination, different-countries

I belong to a team where some of the members are expats. Recently, one of the members made the request to work from his own country appealing that if the request was not accepted, he will resign. I'm in a similar situation and as a plus, I have my son living in my home country.

Before I was even given the chance to ask for similar contract change I was told that my colleague's situation is an exception and that the company is not open to more exceptions.

I would like to know if I should insist on this subject taking it to senior management or CEO or just resign and try to find a position in my country.

current work location is EU state.

Comment: Why have you suddenly decided to quit? You were presumably working quite happily at the job before.

Comment: @DJClayworth true that I happy with what I had, the issue here is that I have my son living abroad and I never consider the chance to work remotely because no one was doing it here in the company. Its just a question of equal rights

Comment: It seems the other person that got remote working only got it because they threatened to leave the company. I don't see why the OP would expect the same result without running the same risk (of having bluff called).

Comment: Is this a private company or a public (or semi-public) body?

Comment: It´s a private company @Smock

Comment: @FrozenButcher you might be out of luck as far as equal rights in the workplace - Private companies don't even have to have equal pay with the same role (although they do need to make sure they don't appear discriminatory). Unless it's stated in your contract that you can have it, or as a company policy, the only way to get it is to threaten the same as the other employee, and pray they think you are valuable enough to keep on as a remote worker.

Comment: I would prefer to raise the question that they are committing a unintentional discrimination, and maybe with this in the future they will open the possibility for me to work remotely. sure Ill keep myself open to opportunities, but I would not like to gamble with my position in the company.

Comment: I don't see a discrimination in treatment. Also that talk about exception might be true. They might have a position needed in company so bad they couldn't afford loosing him. Also change in contract might come with one extra. Payment.

Comment: It may easily be that you don't have the same leverage as the other person - escalating to "if the request was not accepted, he will resign" would reveal whether they believe that you are as irreplaceable as the other person; I can certainly imagine that the practical leverage can be sufficiently different to justify different answers to the same situation - it's perfectly legitimate to discriminate employees based their individual skills, performance and market power (speed/cost to replace) and have different treatment for different employees.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no harm in asking.

Don't bring the example of the "other person" in the equation: make it about **you**. You need to relocate, ask if the organization has provisions to help you or not. I'd not advise to *insist*, have an open minded discussion, let them know of your requirement and whether they are willing to help you to continue working for them.

Given that you **need** to relocate to your home country, and the existing organization says they can't help you in this regard (i.e., allowing remote work), find a new job / organization that will.

Answer (score 1):

Biggest thing is that it's unclear what terms your colleague made. It could be a temporary thing or the company must keep him on board for a project then can let him go. As such, I wouldn't use him as an example as you may say something that they know is untrue and call your bluff on it.

I'd just say you have to relocate to your home country because your son is there and you'd like be there. Tell them that you are willing to continue your work there and would be open to anything. If not, then tell them good bye.

Comment: answering your question @Dan The colleague will have the same permanent position only changing the location to remote.